# Проверка приложения Apple перед выкладкой в AppStore

Tags: ios, apple

Бывает возникает ситуация, что после выкладки приложения в АппСтор Эппл режектит приложение и указывает ошибки, которые на позволяют его выложить. Все ок, но проюлема в том что после отрпавки приложения в АппСтор и до получения ошибок проходит бывает 2-3 дня.
Есть ли способ быстро проверить приложение на ошибки, чтоб не ждать несколько дней, поправить их если они есть а только потом уже выкладывать?

Answer (score 0):

Можно запросить ускоренную проверку в App Store - называется expedited review.
Однако для expedited review должны быть веские основания - фиксы критичных багов, обязательства перед третьими сторонами, юридические договоренности и т.п.
Кроме того, есть ограничение по количеству expedited review, то есть каждый раз его использовать нельзя.